# JAVA adding total

Tags: java, return

I would like to have this function used inside of another function.
what this "addTotal" function does is it returns the total balance of each bankAccount that a certain client has.
I know by inserting the "return total;" statement, it only gets the first bankAccount balance only.
Any suggestion on this one?

```
private int addTotal(ClientList clientList, String name)
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i<clientList.getClientList().size();i++)
        {
            if(name.compareTo(clientList.getClientList().get(i).getName())==0)
            {
                for(int j =0;j<clientList.getClientList().get(i).getBankAccList().size();j++)
                {
                    int total = clientList.getClientList().get(i).getBankAccList().get(j).showBalance();
                    total+=total;   
                     return total; // i know here is the problem. any suggestion on this?
                }
            }
        }
        return -2;
    }
```

Comment: i think you want the return total to be out of the loop. it should be where the return -2 is

Comment: Instead of return int, return a list of int containing all the totals.

Comment: declare `int total  = -2` as the first line , the last line return total. Preferable create a get client method which will do the first for loop

Comment: As a suggestion to improve your method, you might want to surround your code in a `try-catch` block. What would happen if your `ClientList` is `null`? or if `clientList.getClientList()` returns `null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Eran solves your original problem.
Your problem was that you didnt sum up the amounts, you did:

```
total = total;
return total;
```

My suggestion for you is when you have code like this:

```
clientList.getClientList().get(i).getName()
```

make a function in ClientList which gets an integer i and returns the name as follows:

```
public String getClientName(int i)
```

and instead having the long code above, all you have to use is:

```
clientList.getClientName(i)
```

Answer (score 6):

You should declare the `total` variable at the start of the method  and return it at the end of the loops :

```
private int addTotal(ClientList clientList, String name)
{
    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i<clientList.getClientList().size();i++) {
        if(name.compareTo(clientList.getClientList().get(i).getName())==0) {
            for(int j =0;j<clientList.getClientList().get(i).getBankAccList().size();j++) {
                total+=clientList.getClientList().get(i).getBankAccList().get(j).showBalance();
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Edit :

you can make your code more readable by introducing a local variable :

```
private int addTotal(ClientList clientList, String name)
{
    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i<clientList.getClientList().size();i++) {
        Client client = clientList.getClientList().get(i);
        if(name.compareTo(client.getName())==0) {
            for(int j =0;j<client.getBankAccList().size();j++) {
                total+=client.getBankAccList().get(j).showBalance();
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

or even better, by using the enhanced for loop (I made some guesses regarding the names of your classes) :

```
private int addTotal(ClientList clientList, String name)
{
    int total = 0;
    for(Client client : clientList.getClientList()) {
        if(name.compareTo(client.getName())==0) {
            for(BankAccount acct : client.getBankAccList()) {
                total+=acct.showBalance();
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

By using Java 8 Streams you can make it even shorter :

```
private int addTotal(ClientList clientList, String name)
{
    return clientList.getClientList()
                     .stream()
                     .filter(c -> name.compareTo(c.getName())==0)
                     .flatMap(c -> c.getBankAccList().stream())
                     .mapToDouble(BankAccount::showBalance)
                     .sum();
}
```

Comment: @Eran You should have taken out repeated invocations outside of for loop: **clientList.getClientList().get(i).getBankAccList()**.

Comment: @Rajesh Yes, there are many ways to make this method more concise, as my edit shows.

Answer (score 1):

This solutions returns the total outside of the loop. I don't know why you wanted to return the -2, but if it's still needed you can adjust the code.

```
 private int addTotal(ClientList clientList, String name)
                {
                    int total =0;
                    for(int i = 0 ; i<clientList.getClientList().size();i++)
                    {
                        if(name.compareTo(clientList.getClientList().get(i).getName())==0)
                        {
                            for(int j =0;j<clientList.getClientList().get(i).getBankAccList().size();j++)
                            {
                                total+= clientList.getClientList().get(i).getBankAccList().get(j).showBalance();suggesti
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return total;
                }
```

Comment: Just posting a piece of code doesn't help at all. You should explain what you have done to solve the problem so the OP can learn from SO and not just get his program working.

Comment: @TomJonckheere dude, you posted just the code. I was not aware of you editing the post, I mean you could have written the explaination before submitting. Anyway, now you have an explaination.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take total declaration and return statement outside of inner for loop.

Replace you inner for loop with below lines:

```
client_BankAccList = clientList.getClientList().get(i).getBankAccList();
int total = 0;

for(int j = 0; j < client_BankAccList.size(); j++)
{
    total += client_BankAccList.get(j).showBalance();
}
return total;
```

Comment: SungKeun - Your code repeatedly invokes clientList.getClientList().get(i).getBankAccList(). I suggest you change it as shown here.